# How to draw multiple polygons on here map?

Tags: here-api

I have problem when i try to draw more then one polygon on HERE map.
If they are close to each other, they are not showing well.
And behavior when zooming is very bad.

My approach was this:

```
map.objects.add(polygon1);
map.objects.add(polygon2);
map.objects.add(polygon3);
```

You can see bug on screenshot (all should be triangles with same color and opacity)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you use the HERE Maps API **v3** I don't think it should be `map.objects.add`.
Looking at the API Playground [example](https://developer.here.com/api-explorer#maps-js/polygon-on-the-map), I believe the correct way to do it is:

```
map.addObject(polygon1);
map.addObject(polygon2);
map.addObject(polygon3);
```

or:

```
map.addObjects([polygon1, polygon2, polygon3]);
```

API reference:

[H.Map#addObject](https://developer.here.com/javascript-apis/documentation/v3/maps/topics_api_nlp/h-map.html#h-map__addobject)

[H.Map#addObjects](https://developer.here.com/javascript-apis/documentation/v3/maps/topics_api_nlp/h-map.html#h-map__addobjects)

Comment: I am using:
http://js.api.here.com/se/2.5.3/jsl.js

map.addObjects is undefined. Maybe i should try v3...

Comment: Been fiddling around with it and I seem to be getting correct shapes with 2.5.3. Do you have some code showing how you create the polygons?

Comment: Sorry for late response. I tried on some small example, and it works fine, but in my original app, I didn't solve problem jet. I am using closed polyline instead as temp solution.